# Residuals from 1:1 line

Tags: r, scatter-plot, linear-regression, variance

I want to measure the distance between a set of points and a 1:1 line. I can build a linear model and get the residuals from the best fit, but I cant get the measure from a 1:1 line. Any helpful hints?

```
#build a df of random numbers     
x=runif(100, 0, 100)
    y=runif (100, 0, 100)
    df=cbind (x,y)
    df=as.data.frame(df)
#build a linear model    
lm1<-lm(y~x, data=df)
    summary (lm1)
#plot the data, lm best fit and 1:1 (red) line)    
    plot (y~x, data=df, pch=16)
    line (lm1)
    abline abline(0,1, col="red")
#get residulas for the linear model 
y.resid= resid (lm1)
```

Comment: By 1:1 line, do you mean y = 1 * x + 0  ?

Comment: yes that would be the red line on the plot

Comment: Keep in mind that for OLS regression the residuals don't give the (minimal) distance (which is orthogonal), but the difference between expected y value and measured y value for a given x value.

Comment: Could you clarify the question, are you asking for the distance from points to the 1:1 line, or the residuals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the distance between a set of points and a 1:1 line, use

```
dist[x-y=0; (x0,y0)] = abs(x0 - y0) / sqrt(2)
```

ref http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

For your example,

```
par(pty="s")
plot (y~x, data=df, pch=16)
line (lm1)
abline(0,1, col="red")
#get residulas for the linear model 
y.resid= resid (lm1)
a=1;b=-1;c=0
xi = (b*(b*x-a*y)-a*c) / (a^2+b^2)
yi = (a*(-b*x+a*y)-b*c) / (a^2+b^2)
segments(x,y,xi,yi,col="blue")
yr = abs(a*x+b*y+c)/sqrt(a^2+b^2)
hist(yr)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `y-x`, just like @vpipkt suggested. Just for the sake of completeness: you can also create a linear model with fixed coefficients `y-x ~ 0` and take the residual there.

```
resid(lm(y-x ~ 0))
```

Of course this is just more complicated and gives the same result as `y-x`, but it explicitely states that you are taking residuals and not calculating the minimal distance to the line (cf @user3969377's answer).

Answer (score 2):

In the sense of residuals from the model y=x, the distance is simply `y-x'.

```
r = y-x
plot(r~x)
abline(h=0)
```

You can expand this to a more general linear model y = ax + b. Residuals are

```
r = y - ax - b
```